# When using "Evans" jazz voicings what voicings should I use for half-diminished ii chord in minor and tritone substitution chords?

Tags: jazz, chord-voicings

Below is a chart I made of the standard Evans A and B forms (which I have only seen in method books using major key harmony) and my own possibilities for voicings for half-diminished and tritone substitution chords. Are my voicings OK? Are there other standard fingerings I should use?

Note: in the minor key chart I used the flat sign for the 5th and 6th chord tones, but not for the 3rd and 7th where they are assumed to be minor intervals.

```
EVANS STYLE CHORDS

Major Keys --------------------------------------------

CHORD   TYPE A      TYPE B

ii m9   3 5 7 9     7 9 3 5
 V 9    7 9 3 6     3 6 7 9
 I Δ9   3 5 6 2     6 2 3 5

Minor Keys --------------------------------------------

CHORD   TYPE A      TYPE B

ii m7♭5 3 ♭5 7 1    7 1 3 ♭5
 V 7♭9  7 ♭9 3 ♭6   3 ♭6 7 ♭9
 i m9   3 5 7 9     7 9 3 5

Tritone substitution for V7 ---------------------------

CHORD   TYPE A      TYPE B

♭II 7♭5 3 ♭5 7 1    7 1 3 ♭5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Jerry Coker's Jazz Keyboard:

Section 2, the rootless II-V-I

First to establish Coker's major forms with other "standard" voicings...

[image]

Coker's minor forms are...

[image]

For some reason Coker doesn't show any tritone substitutions in section 2 of the booklet. He shows an example in the previous section about rootless voicings for a 12 bar blues where a `G7` in bar 4 is substituted with a `Db7`. He uses an enharmonic spelling to maintain the same spelling for the `3` and `7` between the `G7` and `Db7` which I find hard to read in staff notation (the 9th of `Db7` is spelled `D#` rather than `Eb`!) Regardless, the substitutions are basically the same voicings as the `V7` in II-V-I of section 2...

[image]

...rather than `♭II 7♭5` it seems that `♭II 7♯5♯9` would be Coker's tritone substitution in minor.

Comment: Feels silly answering my own question, but these are the "standard" rootless voicings I am interested in. Coker covers II-V-I in major _and_ minor, and he has a section specifically about these voicings for 12 bar blues. I wish I had found this book sooner.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to favour voicings based on stacked thirds. The book:

[Frank Mantooth Jazz Piano Voicings](https://dokumen.tips/documents/jazz-piano-voicings-mantoothpdf.html)

says to avoid stacked thirds in favour of voicings based on descending fourths.

This descending fourths structure is exactly the chord shape used by **Bill Evans** in his performance of 'So What' with Miles Davis.

I've had a printed copy of the book on my piano music stand for years. The chord spellings are *brilliant* and systematic and they sound proper. Third-based voicings can sound twee.

Two of its chapters are devoted to **diminished chord spellings** and **tritone substitution** respectively.

Comment: I don't favor those voicings. It's just that the Evans voicings seem to be a staple of jazz so I want to study them. My question is if there are Evans voicings for minor and the tritone substitute. But I appreciate the resource about harmony in fourths.

Comment: The idea of Evans voicings is generally to bring out the dissonances peculiar to jazz chords more - and in particular there are usually some 2nds moved inside a 4th instead of being put outside as a 9th.  (I'm not usually a jazz musician and never learned the details, but got the general idea.)